# Two different values for same variable "args"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

I am invoking a method  from python script which has one of the variable as args.
Once I step into the method, when I am trying to see the value of the the variable args, "print args" and  just executing 'args' display two different values.
Can anyone please let me know whats the difference between these two commands.

I expected both the commands to display same value.

```
(Pdb) print args
<lib.framework.testmanager.RunArgs object at 0xb26acac>

(Pdb) args
args = <lib.framework.testmanager.RunArgs object at 0xb26acac>
u = <upgradelib.UpgradeManager object at 0x946cf8c>
spec = {'excludeHosts': None, 'evacuateAllData': True, 'WaitTime': None, 'IssueType': 'Host Disconnect', 'performObjectUpgrade': True, 'downgradeFormat': False}
result = True
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`args` is a PDB debugger command. Use `!args` to show the actual variable.

See the [*Debugger Commands* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands):

> *a(rgs)*
>   Print the argument list of the current function.

and

> *[!]statement*
>   Execute the (one-line) statement in the context of the current stack frame. **The exclamation point can be omitted unless the first word of the statement resembles a debugger command.**

(Emphasis mine).

In your `args` output you can see the `args` argument value on the first line.

Personally, I find the `(a)rgs` command a little pointless; it prints all values using `str()` instead of `repr()`; this makes the difference between objects with similar `__str__` output values invisible (such as `str` vs. `unicode`, or a BeautifulSoup Element vs. a string with HTML, etc.).