# python args variable not working with parser.parse_args

Tags: python, argparse

I am working on a simple script that uses parse_args, but the assignment does not work if the variable name is `args`, as shown in the documentation and multiple examples.

```
(Pdb) parser.parse_args()
Namespace(partition_frequency='daily', start_date='2016-02-03', table_name='test_table')

(Pdb) x=parser.parse_args()
(Pdb) x
Namespace(partition_frequency='daily', start_date='2016-02-03', table_name='test_table')

(Pdb) args=parser.parse_args()
(Pdb) args
      **>> No output**
(Pdb) arg=parser.parse_args()
(Pdb) arg
Namespace(partition_frequency='daily', start_date='2016-02-03', table_name='test_table')
```

Any clues?

Comment: check `args` before and after parsing but without assigning to `args`. maybe parser use it

Comment: `args` is a pdb command. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342420/two-different-values-for-same-variable-args

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are running these commands in `pdb`.

As it turns out, `args` is [a pdb command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)! So it's not being interpreted as a variable, but rather as a command to pdb.

Comment: in 2023 still shoots in the legs

Answer (score 1):

What Python version do you use?
I've just checked this simple example with Python 2.7 and it works
well.

test.py:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='foo of the %(prog)s program')
args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

And it gives me following output:

```
>test.py --foo qqq
Namespace(foo='qq')
```